# How can I use the native Electron WebView tag in VSCode extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to use the native webview api that is provided with Electron in a vscode extension. I noticed through my experiments that this feature does not appear to be available. I was wondering if there is a way to access it and use it? I am specifically interested in using the loadUrl with the baseUrl option. This is not available in the preview pane (only local file resources are loadable from my understanding). Whereas the native webview component supports loading arbitrary URLs. I require this for my toolkit. Any answers or pointers would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported and will likely never be supported.

You can use an `iframe` instead a [VS Code webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/webview) instead

Comment: Is there a way I can expose the Electron API in a private branch?

Comment: Yes, take a look at how the built-in vscode webview is implemented